# Magento 2 : How to change the Availability of my off-line custom payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am developing a custom off-line payment method module in which I want to change the status of this module on certain condition. From where or which method I can change the status of my payment method ?

For example like for some zip-code and order total etc I want to show my payment method.

Comment: You can explain more about the status? Disable or Enable payment?

Comment: On some condition like quote and customer I want to Enable/Disable my payment method

Comment: I think that it's better if hidden or show?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, Is it possible to hidden or show any offline payment method on the basis of shipping zipcode ?

Comment: Yes, I think we can do this. In this weekend, I will take a look your issue.